# Infinite plane of wireframe squares in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to know an efficient way of instantiating an infinitely large, (or effectively infinitely large) plane of criss-crossing lines arranged to form squares.

three.js has a line object, should I just instantiate a large number of these? Or perhaps instantiate one Plane object, and apply some sort of repeating material? Perhaps there are other more efficient ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will give a semi-infinite plane of criss-crossing lines:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( - 500, 0, 0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 500, 0, 0 ) );

linesMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x787878, opacity: .2, linewidth: .1 } );

for ( var i = 0; i <= 20; i ++ ) {

    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, linesMaterial );
    line.position.z = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
    scene.add( line );

    var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, linesMaterial );
    line.position.x = ( i * 50 ) - 500;
    line.rotation.y = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
    scene.add( line );
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error that "Faceless geometries are not supported" in r121

Answer (score 13):

Here is another approach:

```
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 200, 10 );
grid.setColors( 0xffffff, 0xffffff );
scene.add( grid );
```

You can add fog to make the grid blend into the background at the horizon.

```
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000000, 0.0128 );
renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
```

It should look quite nice.

three.js r.71